# A function, which contains a struct, that is declared in the following function?

Tags: c, function, struct, declaration

The follow is my Code:

```
typedef struct Alpha {
int number;
} Alpha;

void setnumber(){
    Beta->number = 1;
}


int main()
{
    Alpha Beta;
    setnumber();
    return 0;
}
```

This just outputs "Error: Beta was not declared in this scope"

How to I declare this, so it works? (without changing the order of typedef, setnumber and main) (Can i pre-declare somethign somehow, If yes, then what and how?)

Comment: In the context of `setnumber` `Beta` was not defined. The compiler error is correct - I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: `Alpha Beta;` is known only in `main`. Even if you also define it in function `setnumber` it will be a *different* variable and will cease to exist when `setnumber` returns.

Comment: @R_Kapp The question is how to declare it right. Sorry for not writing that in my question, thought it was pretty obvious.

Comment: @WeatherVane So how can I do it right, without changing the ordner of typedef, setnumber and main ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this, where `main` passes the address of `Beta` to the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Alpha {
    int number;
} Alpha;

void setnumber(Alpha *Beta) {
    Beta->number = 42;
}

int main(void) {
    Alpha Beta = {0};
    setnumber(&Beta);
    printf("%d\n", Beta.number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well that's not exactly what I was looking for (pre-declarations), but it's a good way to do it, too. Thank you. Sadly I can't upvote your answer, because I'm new. I'll soon give you the green mark instead :)

Comment: There is no other way for the function to know anything about `Beta` apart from accepting either the pointer or the struct istself.